# recalling probability rule

Tags: probability, probability-theory

let us consider following picture ,we have  given some initial data and also list of questions which we should solve

[image]

i would like to  solve part  $e$,as i remember in this case i should use Morgan rule,which means that in part $e$,we should have $p(A')*p(B')=0.8*0.7=0.56$

but i want to make sure that i am right,please  make  me sure that this is right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have $\Pr((A\cup B)')=\Pr(A'\cap B')$. If you draw a Venn Diagram, you should soon see that the required probability is $0.6$. You can also write down the answer directly, if you have already computed $\Pr(A\cup B)$. (This was part b) of the question.)

Multiplication is not appropriate, one does that to find $\Pr(X\cap Y)$ when $X$ and $Y$ are **independent**.

**Added:** You have asked for explicit formulas. So here is one for e). We have
$$\Pr((A\cup B)')=1-\Pr(A\cup B)=1-\left(\Pr(A)+\Pr(B)-\Pr(A\cap B)\right).$$

Comment: Part c), no, multiplication is not right. The answer, as a "formula" is $\Pr(B)-\Pr(A\cap B)$.

Comment: Don't worry about it. The system does not like very long strings of comments, so after an hour or so I will delete mine, and I suggest you delete yours. The delay is so that you will have time to digest all the information contained in the comments. I do not want to add the information to the answer, since the original question you asked was only about e).